# Preparing Data for pivot table: How to add another value to excel cell?

Tags: excel, pivot

I have the following example of a table from which I will create a pivot table. I have hundreds of entries like the ones below:

| Color of car | Year of car |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 1990 |
| Green | 1992 |

However, I want to create the following and make sure it is possible to be used in a pivot table easily so that when i select "color of car" and filter for blue it shows up in both cases. Any ideas?

| Color of car | Year of car |
| --- | --- |
| Blue, Red | 1990 |
| Green, Blue | 1992 |

Comment: Where do the additional information come from?  As is, this looks like random inserts, and as such one would need to manually enter it.  Remember we do not know what you know about your data.

Comment: @ScottCraner the additional data is to come from me. Let's say I have thousands of cells with each one color, but it turns out several cars are actually two due to decals or whatever reason. I want to add this to the dataset to make it so that a blue/red car shows up for both blue and red. I will be adding this data manually, but want to enter it in a way that makes it easiest to create a pivot table going forward

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine as-is. Use the Color as your pivot filter, then search for "blue". It will return all values that fit. Simply check the "select multiple items" box and it works.

[image: Pivot Filter Selection]

[image: After Selection]

Comment: I think you missed the part that the cells will start with only one color and the OP wants to add the second.  The question is how do we know what color to add to which cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm too literal I guess. When he said "make sure it is possible to be used in a pivot table easily", that's the part I answered. I thought he meant the color could be a single value or multiple values. He hasn't shown his pivot table, but rather, only his table. It's a confusing question at the least.